# How can itegrated AutoIT in WebDriver (Selenium Grid) ?

Tags: selenium

I'm launched Selenium Grid (Node and Hub),and testing Web app. But I need provide some action on Windows Open dialog. Can I do that with and how using AutoIt on next way : capabilities.setCapability("browser", "AutoIt") ?

Comment: Are you using AutoItDriverServer? You need to add what you tried so far.

Comment: Now I using Selenium Grid (Hub and Node) from Web Driver (ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    capabilities.setBrowserName(BrowserType.CHROME);
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);). But I don't know how I can instantiate and run  AutoItDriverServer. Do you know some helpful link for this topic?

Comment: How I can install and run AutoItDriverServer ?

Answer (score 1):

Refer [this](https://www.guru99.com/use-autoit-selenium.html) link for step by step guide on how to use AutoIT with Selenium. This involves using the tool to create a .au3 script which you will need to execute from your code. But from your question, if you want something like `capabilities.setCapability("browser", "AutoIt")`, you have to use [AutoItDriverServer](https://github.com/daluu/AutoItDriverServer) (See README for installation steps).

Its a Selenium like Interface wrapper for AutoIt, so you can basically operate your windows application by the very same selenium methods you are familiar with.

### How to Use it:

In the 'autoitdriverserver_python' directory, run the "server.py" file. Now, whenever you want to perform actions on your windows application, just create a **new** remote driver with capability of `'browserName':'AutoIt'`. Ex-

```
driver = webdriver.Remote( command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_capabilities={'browserName':'AutoIt'})
driver.get("path to your application")
driver.switch_to_window("window name")
driver.find_element_by_id("your id").click()
```

Note as mentioned in docs:

> AutoIt doesn't find or handle multiple elements specified by location
>   strategy, therefore, finding elements in WebDriver is not implemented
>   for AutoItDriverServer. You can only find singular elements.

See [this](https://github.com/daluu/AutoItDriverServer/wiki/WebDriver-API-command-support-and-mapping-to-AutoItX-API) link for all the available commands. To locate elements, for example through ID, you need AutoIT info tool which is [available in the entire package](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/).